# Gstreamer demuxing h264 from MJPEG stream from logitec web camera

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Dear friends I have Logitech 925e camera which advertised as camera with built in h264 compression. After I connected it to my PC, I found out that it doesn't show h264 stream as available format. Than I found out that it attach h264 data to MJPEG frames. In order to extract h264 I need to use uvch264mjpgdemux. But I couldn't find any examples of uvch264mjpgdemux usage. Can you show me pipeline example and show how can I manage settings of h264 compression in that case?

I have tried to get h264 stream via uvch264src from 925e camera, but there is internal stream error message

Comment: This question appears to be irrelevant to this platform.

Comment: I found a lot of answers on stackoverflow about gstreamer, so I hope that somebody would help me

Comment: Can you post the pipeline you used that yielded an error?

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 uvch264src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264, width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync = false